# Show that if X is a continuous random variable on $[b,\infty)$ then $\mathrm{E}[X]=b+\int_b^{\infty}(1- F(x))dx $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have to use the definition $$\mathrm{E}[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx $$
and integration by parts. I haven't done an improper integral in a while, so I'm pretty from the beginning that I made a mistake.

$$\mathrm{E}[X]=\int_{b}^{\infty}xf(x)dx $$ since X is from b to infinity
$$ =\lim_{c\to \infty}\left(\int_{b}^{c}xf(x)dx\right)$$ Using I.B.P. I let u=x and dv = f(x)dx, I ended up with
$$ =\lim_{c\to \infty}\left(\biggl[{xF(x)}\biggr]_b^c -\int_{b}^{c}F(x)dx\right)$$ and this is where im stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the same thing with $d(F(x) - 1) = f(x)dx$ instead of $dF(x) = f(x)dx$. You are left with
$$
\lim_{c\to\infty}\left[
 c(F(c)-1) - b(F(b)-1) + \int_b^c (1-F(x))dx
\right]
$$
Now you know that $F(b) = 0$, so it is sufficient to show that
$$
 c(F(c)-1) \to 0
$$
But
$$
 c(1-F(c)) = c P(X > c) \le E[X1 _{X>c}]
$$
Now using the dominated convergence theorem, you can prove that the right had side $\to 0$ when $c\to\infty$. So
$$
\lim_{c\to\infty}\left[
 c(F(c)-1) - b(F(b)-1) + \int_b^c (1-F(x))dx
\right] = b + \int_b^\infty (1-F(x) ) dx 
$$

---

Another proof, using the Fubini theorem in the $\star$ed step:

$$
E[X] - b = E[(X-b)] = 
E\left[
\int_b^\infty 1_{x<X} dx
\right] =^\star \int_b^\infty E[1_{x<X}] dx
= \int_b^\infty P(X>x) dx
$$

Comment: I like your proof, but my gut is telling me that this proof might not be for a measure-theoretic probability class. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: there is another one with the fubini theorem, but this is not the path chosen by OP...

Comment: @Clarinetist: I added the proof.

Comment: +1. That is a great way to approach the proof and the cleanest way I've ever seen it done. :D

Comment: yes, it avoids the embarrassing case when there is no density :)

Answer (score 1):

More directly, note that for every $\xi\geqslant b$, $$\xi-b=\int_b^\xi\mathrm dx=\int_b^\infty\mathbf 1_{\xi\gt x}\mathrm dx.$$ Integrating this identity with respect to the distribution of $X$ and noticing that, for every $x$, $$E(\mathbf 1_{X\gt x})=P(X\gt x)=1-F(x),$$ one gets the desired result.

The existence of a PDF and the complicated integration by parts one sometimes suggests as a way to the result, are simply irrelevant. The method above uses only Tonelli theorem (a.k.a. Fubini theorem for nonnegative functions) on the product measured space $(\Omega\times\mathbb R,\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R),P\otimes\mathrm{Leb})$.